# Cannot access CraftCMS 3 plugin store from local windows environment/MAMP

Tags: dashboard, craftcms

I have installed craft CMS 3 via composer, running on MAMP (windows 10) and successfully created a few templates and entries.

However, When I try to access the plugin store I see the following error on the page: "The Plugin Store is not available, please try again later."
and in the console I see the two internal server errors copied below:

I was able to install the contact form plugin via composer. but not for other plugins (e.g. sprout forms)

I am also seeing an 'unknown error' message at the dashboard: jquery.js:9566 POST http://localhost:81/index.php?p=admin/actions/dashboard/get-feed-items 500 (Internal Server Error)

Has anyone else seen this issue?

Console error messages when trying to access the plugin store:

```
    axios.js:853 GET http://localhost:81/index.php?p=admin/actions/plugin-store/plugin-store-data 500 (Internal Server Error)
    (anonymous) @ axios.js:853
    e.exports @ axios.js:687
    e.exports @ axios.js:1367
    Promise.then (async)
    a.request @ axios.js:525
    a.(anonymous function) @ axios.js:535
    (anonymous) @ axios.js:439
    Q @ main.js:1
    (anonymous) @ main.js:1
    getPluginStoreData @ main.js:1
    (anonymous) @ vuex.js:710
    l.dispatch @ vuex.js:432
    dispatch @ vuex.js:338
    created @ main.js:1
    yt @ vue.min.js:6
    pn._init @ vue.min.js:6
    pn @ vue.min.js:6
    (anonymous) @ main.js:1
    l @ jquery.js:3583
    c @ jquery.js:3651
    setTimeout (async)
    (anonymous) @ jquery.js:3689
    c @ jquery.js:3317
    fireWith @ jquery.js:3447
    fire @ jquery.js:3455
    c @ jquery.js:3317
    fireWith @ jquery.js:3447
    ready @ jquery.js:3920
    B @ jquery.js:3930
    axios.js:853 

    GET http://localhost:81/index.php?p=admin/actions/plugin-store/craft-data 500 (Internal Server Error)
    (anonymous) @ axios.js:853
    e.exports @ axios.js:687
    e.exports @ axios.js:1367
    Promise.then (async)
    a.request @ axios.js:525
    a.(anonymous function) @ axios.js:535
    (anonymous) @ axios.js:439
    W @ main.js:1
    (anonymous) @ main.js:1
    getCraftData @ main.js:1
    (anonymous) @ vuex.js:710
    l.dispatch @ vuex.js:432
    dispatch @ vuex.js:338
    created @ main.js:1
    yt @ vue.min.js:6
    pn._init @ vue.min.js:6
    pn @ vue.min.js:6
    (anonymous) @ main.js:1
    l @ jquery.js:3583
    c @ jquery.js:3651
    setTimeout (async)
    (anonymous) @ jquery.js:3689
    c @ jquery.js:3317
    fireWith @ jquery.js:3447
    fire @ jquery.js:3455
    c @ jquery.js:3317
    fireWith @ jquery.js:3447
    ready @ jquery.js:3920
    B @ jquery.js:3930
```

Comment: update - still getting the same internal 500 errors, but no longer running on localhost:81, instead I am now on localhost only...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

this was a curl 60 error. To fix it, I downloaded cacert.pem from curl.haxx.se/ca/cacert.pem and saved it into the same folder that I have my mamp php version. Then referenced this in php.ini like so:

```
[curl] 
; A default value for the CURLOPT_CAINFO option. This is required to be an 
; absolute path.
curl.cainfo ="{{ path to cacert.pem"}}
```